# Magento UPDATEORDERSSHIPPINGSTATUS command

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a Magento site which uses thub to update the order status and shipping. But once it was migrated to  a diffrent server the api return this

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <RESPONSE Version="4.6"><Envelope><Command>UPDATEORDERSSHIPPINGSTATUS</Command><StatusCode>0</StatusCode><StatusMessage>All Ok</StatusMessage></Envelope><Orders><Order>
<HostOrderID>100016422</HostOrderID><LocalOrderID>22364</LocalOrderID>
<HostStatus>Failed</HostStatus><StatusMessage1>Can not create Invoice</StatusMessage1><StatusMessage2>Filed create Invoice</StatusMessage2><StatusMessage3>Error. Not object shipment.</StatusMessage3></Order></Orders></RESPONSE>**
```

The code as i understand which has issue is as follows

Code 1 :

```
if (!$this->_current_order->canInvoice()) {

            // Added Track and Content
                $this->Msg[] = 'Can not create Invoice';

                  return false;
    }
```

Code 2 :

```
           $_shipments=$this->_current_order->getShipmentsCollection();
              $shipments_array=$_shipments->toarray();

              if (count($_shipments)==0){
                 $this->Msg[] = 'Error. Not object shipment.';
                 $this->result = 'Failed';
                 return false;
              }
```

Will reset() for Mage::getModel("sales/order"); fixed this issue?